# What file sharing sites do you "personally" recommend so my VB.net application can download an update?

Tags: vb.net, download, file-sharing

I have my VB.net application, but I want it do download a new file from somewhere. What would you recommend for this? I know I need a URL for the download but I have tried a few different things and have not got any results.

I was just seeing if anyone could give a link or something to something they have used or know something that can work. - Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

:)
I use SDrive of CoffeCup ( http://www.coffeecup.com ) to store files in case if wanted to download via a VB.NET application or any other.

For an example i upload updates as ZIP files ( http://infinityresearches.coffeecup.com/Netwatch/publish.zip ) to the SDrive so the my applications can download and install the updates by itslef

Answer (score 0):

My friend...

For FTP use you can use

Google Drive as it has a defanit and simple set of APIs
Microsoft Access server as it is simplified to single API
Skydive can also been used